# Can you get database id from an object's object_id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, objectid

Here's my problem: I have a Rails project with two models, People and Credits, and a person has many credits. I only have access to the front-end. I don't have access to the source code, console, or database, but I can see a list of people and a list of credits.

The table of people looks like:
`1 | John | Doe` which is id, first, and last name columns.

The credits table looks like:
`1 | #<Person:0x0000000591aaa0>`, which is the credit id and the active record object id (right?) for the person it belongs to.

Is there anyway to get the database id from the object id for this person?

Comment: If you don't have access to the backend then how would obtaining the id help? Also, to answer your question no you can't determine this from the object_id, it will be different for each page load.

Comment: Object_id is assigned when new obejct is created and does not change when the object is modified. Even more, you can have two objects created from the single rdb row and they will have different object_id. Hence, simple implication, that you cannot get any sort of data from object_id except for the object_id. Apart from that, what kind of task is it? Are you trying to hack sbs website?

Comment: No, no hacking. Just a project I inherited that I'm trying to recreate the database for. @KyleDecot, if I could get the id of the person, then I could associate the credits with the correct people.

Comment: You inherited the project without access to code or database? Then you should tell the owner, that he is looking to get a completely new project, as you have to write it from the scratch. Judging by the credits table, he/she should be happy anyway. Database is not retrievable though.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No you can't, sorry.

Slightly fuller answer:

The database id and the object id are entirely unrelated.

An `object_id` is the reference that ruby makes to a particular instance - ie an object. Whereas the `id` is the value for the primary-key of a single row of the database table.

To illustrate the problem: You could instantiate five objects of class `Person` - each of which has the same data as the first row of the `people` table, and each object will have its own `object_id` but they will all have the same value for the database `id`.

Thus - sadly you can't use `object_id` as a reference to `id`